# Passing the value to form from View - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a view in which i am rendering two forms. Both the forms are related to each other UpdatePayment(sim_form) and AddPaymentForm(payment_form). As you can see from the code that I am populating the form by fetching the ID of sim_form . I want the same ID of sim_form to be saved in model Payment which has a sim foreign key in it. But i am unable to pass the value and the form gives a validation error of having a null value for sim_id.

The id is coming and i am able to use it as well.

model

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    deposit_date = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name='Deposit Date')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    sim = models.ForeignKey(Sim, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False)
```

View

```
def updatePayment(request, id):
    sim  = get_object_or_404(Sim, pk=id)
    payment_form = AddPaymentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        sim_form = UpdatePayment(request.POST, instance=sim)
        try:
            if  payment_form.is_valid() and sim_form.is_valid:
                sim_form.save()

                # I am trying to form the value from here
                payment_form.sim_id = id
                payment_form.save()
                messages.success(request, ("Payment has been updated"))
            else:
                messages.warning(request, ("Data in fields is incorrect, please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, ("Error: {}".format(e)))
    else:
        sim_form = UpdatePayment(instance=sim)
        payment_form = AddPaymentForm(request.POST)
    context = {'sim_form': sim_form,'payment_form': payment_form,}
    return render(request, 'payment/updatePayment.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove `sim` field as it is not required in the model form:

```
class AddPaymentForm(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       model = Payment
       fields = ('deposit_date', 'file')
```

Then update the view to save the `sim` value like this:

```
def updatePayment(request, id):
    sim  = get_object_or_404(Sim, pk=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        payment_form = AddPaymentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        sim_form = UpdatePayment(request.POST, instance=sim)
        try:
            if  payment_form.is_valid() and sim_form.is_valid():
                sim_form.save()
                payment = payment_form.save(commit=False)
                payment.sim_id = id
                payment.save()
                messages.success(request, ("Payment has been updated"))
            else:
                messages.warning(request, ("Data in fields is incorrect, please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, ("Error: {}".format(e)))
    else:
        sim_form = UpdatePayment(instance=sim)
        payment_form = AddPaymentForm()
    context = {'sim_form': sim_form,'payment_form': payment_form,}
    return render(request, 'payment/updatePayment.html', context)
```

Here I am using [**`payment_form.save(commit=False)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to generate a `Payment` object which has not been saved to DB. then I assigned `sim_id` with this object and saved it DB using `.save()` method.